# What is the best way to design the schema for the following?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

What is the best way to design the schema for the following 
requirements?

Need to store Countries, States, Counties, and counties can be divided
into regions. Regions can then have people with various data points
to report on.

Regions can also be further divided into divisions which is 
like grouping people. So Region 1 can have Division A, Division B 
with people in each of these divisions. Regions and Divisions, each have
different set of meta data that are different from Countries, States and Counties.

Reports will be on the data associated with people and similar
to google analytics with drilling down from Country all the 
way down to regions and divisions.

Note: Regions can have 10 peopel and 1 division with 4 people and remaining 6 people
are not tied to any division.

Comment: You might get better responses if you post YOUR thoughts on the best way to do this and ask for verification/improvements rather than asking the community to design your schema for you.

Comment: Can regions and divisions change over time? Do you have to account for things like countries/regions/etc. breaking apart or merging back together? Can people's affiliation with different divisions change over time? And if so, do you care? You might want to read up on the Accountability "analysis" pattern from Martin Fowler if any of these items apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like each person can have one and only one region.

If you are doing transactional processing (as opposed to data mining/warehousing), then I would link the person to the region with a `RegionID` foreign key.

As far as the (optional) divisions, you can either link the person to a division with a link table: `PersonID`, `DivisionID` or if you don't mind `NULL` `DivisionID`, you can have a foreign key.

As far as the hierarchy for the geographic regions, I would hesitate to model this until I knew more about the limitations across countries and what these structures represent.  While it would be nice to think that everything always rolls up to the next level, I've dealt a lot with hierarchies where levels are skipped and these are modeled very differently.  Plus, many countries like the United Kingdom typically would not have States (unless you are going to use England, Scotland, Wales, and Northern Ireland).  [France is even more complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_France).

For the reporting/rollup aspect (or if you are only doing data mining/warehousing), I would transform to a separate dimensional model, which would "lock in" the other things as attributes and make it far easier to do the roll ups.  So the star schema would lock in dimensional IDs for the different levels to the facts.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

- countries,States,counties,cities all have fk to regions.
- states has fk to countries
- counties has fk to states
- cities has fk to counties
- regions has fk to divisions
- people has fk to divisions_people
- divisions_people has fk to people and divisions
- divisions has fk to divisions_people

  ```
  country <- state <- county <- city
    ^          ^         ^      ^
     \          \        /     /
                 regions
                    ^
                    |
                divisions
                    ^
                    |   
                   \|/
              divisions_people (1 person in multiple divisions)
                    ^
                    |
                  people
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A table for countries:
country_id, country_name, population

A table for states:
state_id, state_name, country_id, population

A table for counties:
county_id, county_name, state_id, population

A table for regions:
region_id, region_name, county_id, population

A table for divisions:
division_id, division_name, region_id, population

Validate in your code or through a triggered constraint (depending on your RDBMS) that you don't have a division with 300 people inside a region with only 50 people.  To have people in a region without being in a division, your region population would be 500 while the sum of its divisions would be only 450 (leaving you 50 people in a region but divisionless).